# How to change name of DjangoObjectType field on response data

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django

Right now I have a django model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model, GetMixin):

    logo_url = models.URLField()
```

And attached it up to `DjangoObjectType`.

```
class MyModelType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Now I need to change the field name of `logo_url` of response to look like this `--logo-url` instead of `logoUrl` so I can have this desired result.

```
{
    "data": {
        "myData": {
            "site": {
                "--logo-url": "https://www.company.com/logo.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> UPDATES

This feature is very hard to achieve! I was able to get ahold of extending an objecttype meta and successfully composed the desired field name structure but graphene standard won't allow me to do so:

```
AssertionError: Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but "--logo-url"
does not.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change the schema to use characters that are not allowed in graphQL.  Graphene is raising an `AssertionError` because it follows the graphQL standard.

See [Special characters in GraphQL schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756493/special-characters-in-graphql-schema)